# How to query posts which have more than one specific tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to query specific posts which have both `$apple` and `$orange` tags.

Using `tag__in` returns the list of posts which have either `$apple` or `$orange` tags.

But I want the posts which have them both.

Here's my code:

```
$apple = 276; // tag id of Apple
$orange = 29; // tag id of orange

$args  = array(
    'post_type'     => array(
                        'post',
                        'review',
                        'cardguide'
                    ),
    'taxonomy'      => 'post_tag',
    'posts_per_page'=> - 1,
    'tag__in'       => array(
                        $apple,
                        $orange
                    ),
    'orderby'       => 'id',
    'order'         => 'DESC',

    'meta_key'      => 'event_end_date',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'=> 'AND',
        array(
            'key'    => 'event_start_date',
            'value'  => $today,
            'compare'=> '<=',
            'type'   => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'    => 'event_end_date',
            'value'  => $today,
            'compare'=> '>=',
            'type'   => 'DATE'
        )
    )

);
```

Since I already have a `meta_query` here, so I am kind of confused how to modify it to get the expected output. Adding new arrays for those tags with `=` operator to compare doesn't work wither.

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'=> 'AND',
    array(
        'key'    => 'event_start_date',
        'value'  => $today,
        'compare'=> '<=',
        'type'   => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'    => 'event_end_date',
        'value'  => $today,
        'compare'=> '>=',
        'type'   => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'    => 'tag_id',
        'value'  => $apple,
        'compare'=> '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'    => 'tag_id',
        'value'  => $orange,
        'compare'=> '=',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a tax-query instead of meta-query.

So your code will be something like:

```
$taxQuery = array('relation' => 'AND');

array_push($taxQuery,array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $apple,
));
array_push($taxQuery,array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $orange,
));


// And add in your args like tax-query
$args  = array(
'post_type'     => array(
                    'post',
                    'review',
                    'cardguide'
                ),

'posts_per_page'=> - 1,

'orderby'       => 'id',
'order'         => 'DESC',

'meta_key'      => 'event_end_date',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'=> 'AND',
    array(
        'key'    => 'event_start_date',
        'value'  => $today,
        'compare'=> '<=',
        'type'   => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'    => 'event_end_date',
        'value'  => $today,
        'compare'=> '>=',
        'type'   => 'DATE'
    )
),
'tax_query' => $taxQuery


);
```

Comment: Hey cesare, thanks for showing me the right way. I got my code working in this way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
$pics = DB::table('pictures')
  foreach ($pics as $pica) {
    if ($pica->category !== 1) 
{
     continue;
 }
  echo ...
```